# Problem on Finding the rank from a Matrix which has a variable

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & -1 & -2 & -3 \\
-2 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\
-3 & 3 & 6 & \alpha  \\
7 & -6 & -17 & -17 \end{bmatrix}
$$

> Find the rank when $\alpha=9$ and when $\alpha \neq 9$

I reduced the matrix A by putting to reduced row echleon form and this is what I got :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}  1 & -1 &  -2 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & 3 & -4 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & \alpha-9  \\
0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now For me **both** when $\alpha=9$ it is $r(A)=2$ and also when $\alpha \neq 9$ it is $r(A)=2$.

I am correct in the first part ($r(A)=2$ when $\alpha=9$)

But the correct answer when $\alpha \neq 9$ is $r(A)=3$. How is this possible? How come it's 3? Please help.

Comment: When $\alpha \neq 9$, you have three linear independent rows, don't you? This is exactly the same as rank of a matrix.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski You mean three rows with non zero terms? But what I have been taught is that the rank is determined by how many pivot columns are there, this is how I found that $r(A)=2$ no matter what $\alpha$

Comment: @TheArtist: If $\alpha-9\ne0$, the final column will also be a pivot column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider the "rank" that you give (determined by how many pivot columns are there). And we can reduce the columns of this matrix by adding some columns multiplied by a certain coefficent to other column. Note the four columns $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$.
$$l_1+l_2:
\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 &  -2 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & 3 & -4 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & \alpha-9  \\
0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
$$l_1\times2+l_2\times 3+l_3:
\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 &  0 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & -4 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & \alpha-9  \\
0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
$$l_1\times3+l_2\times(-4)+l_4:\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & \alpha-9  \\
0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now it is clear that there are three independent columns in this matrix when $\alpha\neq9$.

In fact for a square matrix, the number of independent columns equals to the number of independent rows. This critical number is the rank of this matrix.

Comment: Understood :D Thank you loads

Comment: But wait a second, is there something called the REDUCED COLUMN ECHLEON FORM? How did you do this? Is this valid?

Comment: you transpose the matrix, put it in row echelon form, then take another the transpose, and the resulting matrix is in column echelon form.